# How to make #Error to Empty in RDLC Report Expressions?

Tags: rdlc

My Report had `AmountColumn(Fields!Amount) & Amount%Column`. I am calculating Grand Total for both the columns using expressions.

I am getting #Error in `GrandTotal of Amount%Column` when `AmountColumn` is Empty.
How to make GrandTotal of Amount%Column as Empty instead of **#Error**.

My Expression Showing #Error:

```
=FormatNumber(Sum(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value))/Sum(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),"Tablix2")*100,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value),"NA",FormatNumber(Sum(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value))/Sum(CDec(Fields!Amount.Value),"Tablix2")*100,4))
```